# Is there an inline element that adds text, so there is not line break?

Tags: html, css

The reason i am asking this is because i have links on my site that are bolded when hovered over, they are "Our Work | Contact us", but the problem is that the "|" is a part of one of the links therefore it is also bolded, is there anyway around this?

Comment: Please give your code to us to play

Comment: Is my answer is not useful?

Comment: @Bharadwaj im relatively new to programming so I do not really know what that is

Comment: I am using mobile phone to post answer. So I am unable to add an example. For 'a' tag add the code that I posted, as <a style="white-space:nowrap;">

Comment: No inline element except `<br>` adds line break. If this is about preventing normal wrapping, you should say that. How does bolding relate to line breaks? You should post your code and specify what exactly is the problem. “Our Work | Contact us” sounds like two links. If you have them as one link, then fix that problem first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css and a border (which is the proper way, not a pipe-sign)

```
<a> text </a>
<a> text </a>
<a> text </a>
<a> text </a>

a{
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 20px; /* this is to center it with the text */
}
a+a{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reg9z/)

Comment: Maybe he WANTS a pipe to be there... ;)

Comment: Clever answer. Unfortunately this guy asks 50 questions and doesn't approve a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use style="white-space:nowrap;" for the container having text to avoid line break.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for this kind of structure

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Our work </a></li>
    <li> | </li>
    <li><a href="#"> contact us </a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
ul > li{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgMVv/)

**EDIT**

without hard coded pipe

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Our work </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About us </a></li>
</ul>


ul{
    list-style:none;
}

ul > li{
    float:left;
}

ul > li a{
    padding:5px;
}

li + li::before {
    content: "|";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgMVv/1)

Comment: Better display `|` via CSS, as it’s hardly a list item.